# (Ruby) is it possible for a shebang to have a "backup" version of ruby?

Tags: ruby, rvm, shebang

Let's say I have a shebang in a ruby script like this:

```
#!/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p647/bin/ruby
```

But the script is being run on four different servers and managed by one git repo (which I'd rather not branch ad infinitum).

One of the servers has 2.0.0-p647, one of them has 2.0.0-p598, one has 2.0.0-p643 and one has only ruby 2.1.1.  The script requires the use of negative lookbehinds in regular expressions, which means it must use 2.0.0 or higher.

This negates the ability to use defaults, because the default installation on at least one of the servers is 1.9.3, and I cannot change the defaults or have the defaults changed.

Is there a way to set up a shebang such that it will "fall back" on a different ruby version if the preferred one is not available?

Comment: ... This sounds more like a server administration issue.

Comment: It is, ultimately, but sometimes when these things happen you need to work around them until they can be fixed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev 

Symlinks!  Why didn't I think of that.

Thanks mate, if you make it an actual post I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @MaxwellEvans: might as well upvote it :)

Comment: @MaxwellEvans: what Dave meant is that there's a special site for this type of questions, http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm a terrible admin and this may well go against RVM principles, but isn't a solution obvious?

**Symlinks**! Make shebangs use `/usr/local/bin/ruby` (or something like that) and on each machine make that path a symlink to the installed ruby.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and then just make sure that the ruby you want is in the environment

Comment: Doesn't this mean loading RVM into a (possibly non-interactive) shell?

Comment: well it would mean adding the RVM directory into the path. Don't see it as much different than the symlink route.